# Querying a pandas dataframe column which has values as list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as given below.

```
import pandas as pd


raw_data = {'score': [1,2,3], 
        'tags': [['apple','pear','guava'],['truck','car','plane'],['cat','dog','mouse']]}


df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['score', 'tags'])
```

`df.query("score==1")` gives the first row as result.

But `df.query("tags='apple'")` gives error.

How to write query for the column 'tags'.

Comment: You've stored lists in your df, the `query` method is unable to evaluate your expression to handle this. To filter the df you'd need to do `df[df['tags'].apply(lambda x: 'apple' in x)]`. Storing non-scalar values in a df is non-performant, you can't expect the usual pandas operations to work like normal

Comment: @EdChum, Oops, edited my post at the same time. But I'm going to add another alternative too :)

Comment: @jpp no worries I'm sure there is a dupe for this although not specifically for getting `query` to handles lists

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `pd.DataFrame.query` to test membership of a string in lists within a series of lists. Holding lists in Pandas dataframes is not recommended as you lose vectorised functionality.

With your existing dataframe, you can instead calculate a mask using `pd.Series.apply`:

```
res = df[df['tags'].apply(lambda x: 'apple' in x)]

print(res)

   score                  tags
0      1  [apple, pear, guava]
```

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = df[['apple' in x for x in df['tags']]]
```

A third option is to use `set`:

```
res = df[df['tags'].apply(set) >= {'apple'}]
```

The last option, although expensive, may suit when you are testing for existence of multiple tags. In each case, we are constructing a Boolean series, which we then use to mask the dataframe.